# XBRL Generator(Mapping tool)

Tags: mapping, generator, xbrl

I am now developing an accounting web application to generate XBRL file then post to a government host web service. Now I have taxonomy prepared and user data ready. What I need is a software which can quickly map those data base on the taxonomy and generate XBRL files. Could anyone provide me some software which can achieve this? Open source is the best that I can implement into my project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think finally I decided to build XBRL file line by line all by myself. And it turns out that it didn't take a lot of time for this procedure. If anyone has questions about building XBRL files, I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

XBRL is a broad area, from detailed accounting data (XBRL GL) to summary reports to highly dimensional, data warehouse type content.

Commercially, products like Altova MapForce are really good for mapping from underlying data sources to XBRL taxonomies and creating content.

I assume you have already looked through SourceForge and found tools like Gepsio (https://gepsio.codeplex.com/). Arelle is a great start for people who know Python. (www.arelle.org). And there is a ton of Open Source and XBRL at xbrlwiki.info.

Comment: I am Gepsio's author. I appreciate you mentioning it as an XBRL tool. Thank you! I should point out that, at this time, Gepsio reads and validates existing XBRL instances, but does not generate new ones. Since the question is asking about generating new XBRL instances, Gepsio wouldn't be appropriate for this particular case. Once XBRL is generated, however, Gepsio fully supports reading, parsing, and validating XBRL instances. Thank you again for the mention!